# Convergence radius for Cauchy multiplication series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ with convergence radius $R_1$, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n x^n$ with convergence radius $R_2$.

Let $R$ be the convergence radius of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n x^n$ with $c_n := \sum_{i+j=n} a_i b_j$.

Find an example where $max(R_1,R_2) \lt R \lt \infty$

---

So I've been on this for hours. I figure $\sum a_n$ needs to get canceled at $R_2$ and $\sum b_n$ needs to get canceled at $R_1$ so for example if I choose $R_1,R_2 = 2,3$ then I need the sums to be something like:$$\sum a_n = {x-2 \over x-3}, \sum b_n = {x-3 \over x-2}$$.

Still I have two main problems. First, I have no idea how to recreate the original series' from the sum I wish they will have. Secondly, it seems like unless I add something else their Cauchy multiplication series will just be a infinite sum of 1's which has radius 0.

I apologize in advance I may have a lot of wrong assumptions in here and I would really like help that actually goes down to details and small passes from one phrase to another because I'm really not figuring this out after seeing many examples which weren't detailed enough. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you asking how to write ${x-2 \over x-3}$ as power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ ?

Comment: The product is the constant function $1 = 1 + 0x + 0x^2 + \cdots$, with $R=\infty$ as convergence radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track!

Here's a way to successfully apply your idea . . .

If $f,g$ are given by
\begin{align*}
f&=
\frac{2-x}{(1-x)(3-x)}
=
\frac{1}{2(1-x)}
+
\frac{1}{2(3-x)}
\\[4pt]
g&=
\frac{1-x}{(2-x)(4-x)}
=
\frac{3}{2(4-x)}
-
\frac{1}{2(2-x)}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
then we have
$$
fg
=
\frac{1}{(3-x)(4-x)}
=
\frac{1}{3-x}
-
\frac{1}{4-x}
$$
and it follows that

- $f$ can be expressed as a convergent power series about $x=0$ with radius $R_1=1$.$\\[4pt]$

  $g$ can be expressed as a convergent power series about $x=0$ with radius $R_2=2$.$\\[4pt]$

  $fg$ can be expressed as a convergent power series about $x=0$ with radius $R=3$.

Note that each of the parts of the partial fraction decompositions of $f,g,fg$ can be expressed as a geometric power series.

Then for $f$ we have
\begin{align*}
f&=
\frac{1}{2(1-x)}
+
\frac{1}{2(3-x)}
\\[4pt]
&=
{\large{\sum_{n=0}^\infty}}
\Bigl(
{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}
\Bigr)
x^n
+
{\large{\sum_{n=0}^\infty}}
\Bigl(
{\small{\frac{1}{6}}}
{\cdot}
{\small{\frac{1}{3^n}}}
\Bigr)
x^n
\\[4pt]
&=
{\large{\sum_{n=0}^\infty}}
\Bigl(
{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}
+
{\small{\frac{1}{6}}}
{\cdot}
{\small{\frac{1}{3^n}}}
\Bigr)
x^n
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
and for $g$ we have
\begin{align*}
g&=
\frac{3}{2(4-x)}
-
\frac{1}{2(2-x)}
\\[4pt]
&=
{\large{\sum_{n=0}^\infty}}
\Bigl(
{\small{\frac{3}{8}}}
{\cdot}
{\small{\frac{1}{4^n}}}
\Bigr)
x^n
-
{\large{\sum_{n=0}^\infty}}
\Bigl(
{\small{\frac{1}{4}}}
{\cdot}
{\small{\frac{1}{2^n}}}
\Bigr)
x^n
\\[4pt]
&=
{\large{\sum_{n=0}^\infty}}
\Bigl(
{\small{\frac{3}{8}}}
{\cdot}
{\small{\frac{1}{4^n}}}
-
{\small{\frac{1}{4}}}
{\cdot}
{\small{\frac{1}{2^n}}}
\Bigr)
x^n
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
and for $fg$ we have
\begin{align*}
fg&=
\frac{1}{3-x}
-
\frac{1}{4-x}
\\[4pt]
&=
{\large{\sum_{n=0}^\infty}}
\Bigl(
{\small{\frac{1}{3}}}
{\cdot}
{\small{\frac{1}{3^n}}}
\Bigr)
x^n
-
{\large{\sum_{n=0}^\infty}}
\Bigl(
{\small{\frac{1}{4}}}
{\cdot}
{\small{\frac{1}{4^n}}}
\Bigr)
x^n
\\[4pt]
&=
{\large{\sum_{n=0}^\infty}}
\Bigl(
{\small{\frac{1}{3}}}
{\cdot}
{\small{\frac{1}{3^n}}}
-
{\small{\frac{1}{4}}}
{\cdot}
{\small{\frac{1}{4^n}}}
\Bigr)
x^n
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: Note: If you want the series to start at $n=1$ rather than $n=0$, just replace $f,g,fg$ by $xf,xg,x^2fg$.

Comment: Perfect i really appreciate the help!

I'm still struggling figuring the way to display these sums as power series'. 

So far I figured: $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {3^{n+1} +1 \over -6 \times 3^n} x^n$$

and: $$g(x) =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n x^n =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {2^{n+1} -3 \over 8 \times 4^n} x^n$$

But I still can't seem to figure out how the final sum looks: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n = ?$$

Comment: @MathStudent101: See my latest edit.